# Connection refused between docker express servers

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, microservices

I am trying to make a connection between two docker containers that are running express servers. In this instance, I would like to use routes in the tasks server within usermanagement server. I implemented [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) in the usermanagement server like this:

```
app.use('/api/tasks', proxy('http://tasks-service:5002/api/tasks'));
```

however, when I make an api call I get the error

```
{
  "err":"connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.6:5002"
}
```

I have installed cors on both servers and linked them up within the same network with docker-compose (below)

[image: docker-compose].

What causes the error? how do I solve it?

Comment: It looks like you’ve attached an image to your question instead of your `docker-compose.yml` file.  Can you replace that image with the text contents of the file?

Answer (score 0):

simple mistake

docker-compose.yml

```
tasks-service:
  ...
  ports:
    - "5002:3000" # <-- wrong
    - "3000:5002" # <-- right, "<hostPort>:<containerPort>"
  ...
```

By doing this your proxy should connect

Answer (score 0):

Your task service is running at 3000 port and you're mapping it to host's 5002 port
So, your code should be:

```
app.use('/api/tasks', proxy('http://tasks-service:3000/api/tasks'));
```

You don't have to map ports to make it work btw.